# Is the sum of the reciprocals of Ramanujan primes divergent?

Tags: number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, divergent-series

I have read many a wonderful proof that the sum of the reciprocals of the primes is divergent and I know that the sum of the reciprocals of twin primes does not diverge, but do we know any results concerning the sum of the reciprocals of Ramanujan primes?

Comment: The Wikipedia page has the bound $2n\ln(2n)<R_n<4n\ln(4n)$, so it looks like it diverges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The divergence follows from the bounds $2n\ln2n < R_n < 4n\ln4n$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_prime).

Comment: Why is this true? Is it well known that $\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{log(k)}$ diverges or something?

Comment: $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n\ln n}$ diverges by integral test.

Comment: Very informative, thank you!